# Почему цвет View не правильный

Tags: java, android, textview, color

Мне нужно поменять цвет TextView с чёрного на красный. В res/values/color добавил строку

`<color name="red">#FFFF0000</color>`

В активности добавил код

```
int colorMy = R.color.red;
textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setTextColor(colorMy);
```

В результате textView  становится синим, а не красным. Подскажите, в чём моя ошибка и как её исправить?

Comment: какой цвет, если сделать textView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,0,0)); ?

Comment: если пишу textView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,0,0))- то всё работает. Но почему не работает мой вариант? Мне хотелось бы брать цвет из ресурсов

Comment: а если без альфа канала - #FF0000 ?

Comment: Если убираю альфу, то ничего не меняется. Цвет синий.

Comment: а как xml целиком выглядит?

Comment: Может `#FF0000FF`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int colorMy = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red);
```

или

```
int colorMy = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red);
```

Comment: работают оба варианта. Я только не могу понять, почему int colorMy = R.color.red; ссылается на какой-то другой цвет. Ведь я же обращаюсь к конкретному ресурсу напрямую. А получаю ссылку совсем на другой объект

Comment: Если пишу int photo1 = R.drawable.funghi;, а потом imageView.setImageResource(photo1);, то всё работает, а с цветом не работает

Comment: я не вникал, но, вроде бы, т.к. цвет это ресурс, то в нему надо как-то по-другому обращаться. Т.е. R.color.red и getColor(R.color.red) это разные значения.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что R.color.red в итоге будет просто число в Int, который вы и подставляете в setTextColor, получаете какой-то другой цвет...

a getColor(R.color.red) получает именно значение, что записано по вашему R.color.red в xml, то есть #FFFF0000

Comment: В этом есть определённая логика. Но почему тогда если пишу int photo1 = R.drawable.funghi;, а потом imageView.setImageResource(photo1);, то всё работает, а с цветом не работает?

Comment: Потому что метод `setImageResource()` ожидает идентификатор ресурса и сам получает по нему картинку, а метод `setTextColor()` ожидает непосредственно цвет, но поскольку цвет и идентификатор имеют одинаковый тип `int`, то не возникает конфликта, а получается не то что вы ожидали. Идентификатор `R.color.red` не хранит в себе непосредственно само значение - это авто-сгенерированное число, ключ к ресурсу, который хранит нужное значение.